# PHP : Execute every 15 records from 900 records

Tags: php

I am having for each loop which is getting records from DB around 900 records.Maximum execution time is set.Now I want every time 15 records should be checked and the executed record should be saved in another column of same table .

But how can I get another batch of 15 records in next iteration,it should check "checked words",if record exists in "checked words" then it should not be iterated again.(1st loop : 1-15 then 2nd loop : 16-20)

Example :

```
             my_db 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 id   | words                   | email      | checked_words
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1   |  a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h.......   | example@example.com |
```

if 'a' is iterated then :

```
             my_db 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 id   | words                   | email      | checked_words
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1   |  b,c,d,e,f,g,h.......   | example@example.com |a
```

So far I have tried :

```
           $flag = 0;
            
            foreach($db_array as $arr){
                
                if($flag >= 15 )
                    break;
            $flag++;
             $searched_result[] = $arr; 
       
        
        }
           
        
        //insert into checked_words columns
       
        $search_words= implode (",",$searched_result);
        $searched_words =insertWordresults($search_words,$db_combinations['id']); //function for inserting words
```

Comment: Use [`LIMIT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) to get only 15 records from the database. Depending on how you keep track of the processed records you can either use a `WHERE` clause that excludes the processed records (and `LIMIT 15`) or use `LIMIT` with two arguments (offset and limit). The latter approach assumes you store somewhere the number of already processed records (offset) and requires a query that always produce the rows in the same order.

Comment: Can you re-phrase this part of your question "I want every time 15 records should be checked"? Its not entirely clear what you're asking

Answer (score 1):

We do not need to reinvent wheel we have PHP **array_chunk** function that do the job for us. Do your logic accordingly in foreach. I give you an example to insert for every 15 records.

```
$result = $db->rawquery("select * from your_9000_record_table");
    
    // Chunk Results by 15
    $chunk = array_chunk($result, 15);

         foreach ($chunk as $chunk_arr) {

                  $tmp_arr = array();
                  foreach ($chunk_arr as $segment) {
                       $tmp_arr [] = $segment;
                  }
                  
                  $sql = "insert into checked_words (
                                         words, email, checked_words
                                         ) values ";
                            
                  $array_keys = array_keys($tmp_arr);
                  $last_key = end($array_keys);

                  foreach ($tmp_arr as $key => $data) {
                  if ($last_key == $key) {
                  $sql .= "(" . implode(",", $data) . ") ";
                  } else {
                  $sql .= "(" . implode(",", $data) . "),";
                  }
                  }

                 $db->rawQuery($sql);
                 unset($tmp_arr);
       }
```

Updated answer with delay.

```
$chunk_15 = array_chunk($result, 15);

        foreach ($chunk_15 as  $chunk_arr) {

            // Chunk 15 records to 5
            $chunk_5_arr = array_chunk($chunk_arr, 5);
            foreach ($chunk_5_arr as $interval_key => $chunk) {

                if($interval_key !== 0){
                    sleep(2);
                }
                // Insert 3 record in one time start ============
                $tmp_arr = array();
                foreach ($chunk as $segment) {
                    $tmp_arr [] = $segment;
                }

                $sql = "insert into checked_words (
                                         words, email, checked_words
                                         ) values ";

                $array_keys = array_keys($tmp_arr);
                $last_key = end($array_keys);

                foreach ($tmp_arr as $key => $data) {
                    if ($last_key == $key) {
                        $sql .= "(" . implode(",", $data) . ") ";
                    } else {
                        $sql .= "(" . implode(",", $data) . "),";
                    }
                }
                //your db server
                $db->rawQuery($sql);
                unset($tmp_arr);
                // Insert 3 record in one time end ============

            }

        }
```

Comment: Thank you!! But I have one more situation that in a chunk of 15 records,first 5 records should execute normally ,then second 5 records will have delay of 2 sec and 3rd chunk of 5 records will have delay of 2 sec.Can you please include this logic in answer.  I was doing : if($flag % 5 == 0) {
                    sleep(2);
                }

Comment: Answer Updated.

Answer (score 0):

For made an action each 15 records you need to make au modulo operation in your count variable like that :

```php
$flag = 0;
            
foreach($db_array as $arr){
     if( ($flag % 15) == 0 ){
          // do what you want for each 15 records
     }

     $flag++;
}
```

The modulo 15 will return 0 each time your reach the next 15 records.